# vb.net Set listbox items equal to an integer

Tags: vb.net, listbox, integer, equals-operator

I have a list box with lots of options (198 to be exact) and they are names of items.
I need to convert each name to be equal to an integer (the item id) so I can write that number to a file.

For example, if they selected the first item, then the integer would be set equal to 3000 but if they picked the second item, it would be 3001 and so on.

I hope you can understand, wasn't sure how to word it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `dataTable` to the `ItemSource` of your `listBox`. The `DataTable` can obviously have more than one field in it. You'll have to configure the properties of the list box to set one of it's fields (the string to display) as visible, then have the other field as `visible = false`. In one of the events (such as `selectedItemChange` i think) access the item's `SelectedItem` that corresponds to the id field.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ENUMERATION and assign each item a value such as below

```
Public Enum MyCountryCodes As Integer
  drzCOUNTRY_UNKNOWN = 0
  drzCOUNTRY_AFGHANISTAN = 1
  drzCOUNTRY_ALBANIA = 2
  drzCOUNTRY_ALGERIA = 3
  drzCOUNTRY_AMERICANSAMOA = 4
  drzCOUNTRY_ANDORRA = 5
  ... etc etc
  drzCOUNTRY_YEMEN = 241
  drzCOUNTRY_ZAMBIA = 242
  drzCOUNTRY_ZIMBABWE = 243
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    MsgBox(ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 3000)
End Sub
```